# Querying related table data with Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

i have a problem trying to get records from a model based on a related table.

I have two tables one called `leads` and one called `recycle_logs`, my app will basically send the same record in the `leads` table like once a month, and when it does so i'll store a new record in `recycle_logs`.

The problem is that i need to select all `leads` with a specific `campaign_id` value and that have a specific `status` that is different from `invalid`, so far so good, now the problem is i need to get them only if they don't have any `recycleLogs` associated with them OR if the last `recycleLog` associated with that particular `lead` is older than `30` days ago for instance.

What i currently have looks somewhat like this.

```
    $leads = $this->leadModel->where(Lead::CAMPAIGN_ID, $this->campaignID)
                ->where(Lead::DUPLICATED, Lead::DUPLICATED_NO)
                ->where(Lead::LEAD_STATUS, "!=" ,Lead::LEAD_STATUS_INVALID)
                ->orderBy(Lead::CREATED_AT, 'desc')
                ->with(
                    ['leadRecyclingLog' => function($query) {
                        $query->where(LeadRecyclingLog::CREATED_AT, '<', (new Carbon())->subDays($this->configRecyclingDays))
                            ->orWhere(LeadRecyclingLog::ID, null);
                    }]
                )
                ->get();
```

What exactly am i doing wrong? It always selects the same number of records regardless of me adding or removing `recycleLogs`

I've managed to get it done through a raw SQL query which i'll post below in case it helps anyone, i'd still like to know how to do it in Eloquent/Query Builder.

```
SELECT * FROM `leads` LEFT JOIN `lead_recycling_logs` ON `leads`.`guid` = `lead_recycling_logs`.`original_lead_guid` WHERE `leads`.`campaign_id` = :campaignID AND `leads`.`duplicated` = 0 AND `leads`.`lead_status` != :invalidStatus AND (`lead_recycling_logs`.`id` IS NULL OR `lead_recycling_logs`.`created_at` < :recyclingDate) ORDER BY `leads`.`created_at` DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$leads = $this->leadModel->where(Lead::CAMPAIGN_ID, $this->campaignID)
    ->where(Lead::DUPLICATED, Lead::DUPLICATED_NO)
    ->where(Lead::LEAD_STATUS, "!=" ,Lead::LEAD_STATUS_INVALID)
    ->orderBy(Lead::CREATED_AT, 'desc')
    ->where(function($q) {
        $q->whereHas('leadRecyclingLog', function($q) {
            $q->where(LeadRecyclingLog::CREATED_AT, '<', (new Carbon())->subDays($this->configRecyclingDays));
        })
        ->orWhereHas('leadRecyclingLog', '<', 1); // Where count of the relationship is smaller than 1
    })->get();
```

I assumed the first part of the query is working well (up until the relationship).

What you're looking for is `->whereHas(relationship)`, not `->with(relationship)`. `->with(relationship)` will attach the associated results to the original model (the query for the original model will not be affected by `->with()`). `->whereHas(relationship)` filters the original model by the condition.

Comment: orWhereDoesntHave is not a method of Query Builder, as such this also doesn't work. I've managed to replicate what i want in a simple MySQL raw query which works just fine, i'll add it to the question it if helps.

Comment: orWhereHas's second argument must be a closure

Comment: got it to work by modifying your query slightly, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work through @devk 's help

```
    $leads = $this->leadModel->where(Lead::CAMPAIGN_ID, $this->campaignID)
        ->where(Lead::DUPLICATED, Lead::DUPLICATED_NO)
        ->where(Lead::LEAD_STATUS, "!=" ,Lead::LEAD_STATUS_INVALID)
        ->orderBy(Lead::CREATED_AT, 'desc')
        ->where(function($q) {
            $q->whereHas('leadRecyclingLog', function($q) {
                $q->where(LeadRecyclingLog::CREATED_AT, '<', (new Carbon())->subDays($this->configRecyclingDays));
            })
                ->doesntHave('leadRecyclingLog', 'or');
        })->get();
```